# Change computer name with VB.net

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to change the computer name of a PC with VB.net using this code:

```
Declare Auto Function SetComputerName Lib "kernel32" (ByVal lpComputerName As String) As Integer

computerName = "Testing"

    SetComputerName(computerName.ToString)
```

Is this right? Because it doesn't change the computer name.

Really preciate your help.

Comment: Did you run your application elevated with admin rights ? P.S. you should check the result of the function and if it fails, check the error with `GetLastError`.

Comment: Have you restarted the computer? SetComputerName "Sets a new NetBIOS name for the local computer. The name is stored in the registry and the name change takes effect the next time the user restarts the computer."

Comment: In your real code, did you check the return value?

Comment: The return value is 1. After I did the change I restart the PC but nothing

Answer (score 0):

I've gotten this to work in the past by having my vb.net code generate a bat file and then execute it. the bat script contains the wmic command for renaming the PC.

```
wmic computersystem where name="%computername%" call rename name="[NEW PC NAME]"
```

you can compile the new name right into the bat file on the fly. The vb.net code just needs to obtain the new name with an argument, or if you're using a windows form, a text box.

VB PART:

```
Public rename As String = "wmic computersystem where name=""%computername%"" call rename name="
...
dim source as new system.text.stringbuilder
source.AppendLine("@echo off")
source.AppendLine(rename + """" + [put your new hostname here] + """")
source.AppendLine("shutdown /r -t 10") 'PC rename only works after reboot. omit this line to reboot later
source.AppendLine("del %0") 'this will make the bat file delete itself after it runs
IO.File.WriteAllText("source.bat", source.ToString())
process.start("source.bat")
```

Do keep in mind this has absolutely no error checking other than what is already built into wmi. You'll need some more code if you want to do things like check for whitespaces, prohibited characters or ensure that the new hostname string is less than 15 characters which is the max set by Windows. This will also only work if the vb.net code is executed with administrator rights. You may also see the Windows CMD briefly open.